# How to find log-likelihood of multiple sequences for hmm using Kevin Murphy toolkit for MATLAB

Tags: matlab, algorithms, likelihood, hidden-markov-model

I have an observation sequence of TPM, EPM and prior. I want to find the log-likelihood of around 100 sequences of length 10 at a time. How can I do this using a forward algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

Since you said you are using Kevin Murphy toolbox, the easiest way to calculate the loglikelihood of the sequences in the discrete case is to use the function named:

[loglik, errors] = dhmm_logprob(yourSequences,initialMat,transitionMat,emissionMat)

Given that you have nStates and nEmissionSymbols

- yourSequences is a cell array storing your multiple sequences.
- The initialMat is the initial probabilities on the states of the hmm model.It has size 1xnStates
- The transitionMat is the transition matrix that contain the probabilities of transitioning between the states of the model.Its size is nStatesxnStates
- The emissionMat is the emission matrix that contains the probabilities of observing the emission symbols given a state of the model.Its size is nStatesxnObservations

For the continuous case there is similar function named:

[loglik, errors] = mhmm_logprob(data, prior, transmat, mu, Sigma, mixmat)

You only have to specify your arguments to the function as in the discrete case.